# How to find the period of the modular function?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I would like to ask how to find the period of the modular function $f(x) = 2^x \pmod{15}$ where $x$ is positive integers.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose $k$ is the period.

$f(x + k) = 2^{x+k} \ = 2^k \cdot 2^x$

The function has a period of $k$ if and only if $2^k = 1 \mod 15$.

We want to solve for the smallest $k$, otherwise the period would be wrong, otherwise we could say that $g(x) = \text{is } x \text{ even?}$ has a period of 4.

From the equation above we get:

$15n = 2^k - 1 | n \in \mathbb{N} \Longrightarrow n = \dfrac{2^k-1}{15}$

And the easiest way to solve $k$ is trial and error using the equation above ($k$ is the period if $\dfrac{2^k-1}{15}$ is an integer), usually this is very fast to do, otherwise you will need some modular arithmetic to solve the equation above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another question. Let's say we are making a truth table for the function from x=0 to x=10. Then, we will get the results in series like 1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8,1,2,4. From this table, can we say that we can get the period? Or is it just a speculation?

Comment: It is just speculation until you do the formal proof, but that is the easiest part, you just need to isolate the $k$ part from the equation and show that it is congruent to $1 \mod \text{number here}$.

Comment: So even though we can speculate the period from the truth table, if we don't follow the formal proof, we can't say the exact period, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: But, doesn't the modular function always return 1 in the starting point of the next period like 1,2,4,8,1... ? If so, it seems like we can find the period also from the truth table. What do you think about it?

Comment: @James we can't, the 1 could be preceded by the 8 in the first 100 elements of the table, and then the 100th 8 is followed by a 2. (though such a function would be very complex)

Comment: I was thinking like you but can't we say that your proof is the same as finding the next 1 as the truth table does?

Comment: Based on the multiplicative order, the modular function has a period when 1 appears again as you can see in this page, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order

Comment: > I was thinking like you but can't we say that your proof is the same as finding the next 1 as the truth table does?

Now I'm confused, which truth table you mean?

Comment: > Based on the multiplicative order, the modular function has a period when 1 appears again

That is correct. It is correspondent to "the first integer result of this equation".

Comment: I mean when I put x from 0 to 10 to the given function $f(x)$, I will get 1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8,1,2,4. This is the truth table that I'm saying and as you can see there, 1 is being repeated. Based on the multiplicative order, it seems like we can exactly find the right period from the truth table. But I'm wondering if it is just speculation or not. Again my questions is that : can we say that we can get the right period from the truth table of this modular function based on the modular function property of multiplicative order?